# Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync() makes the app to crash

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, geolocation

I need to get device location in Xamarin.Forms application or iOS.

I have added 'Location When In Use Usage Description' key in info.plist, and in shared project, I am calling this:

```
await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
```

That instruction makes the app to crash. This is in the log:

```
=================================================================

Native Crash Reporting
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

used by your application.
=================================================================

Basic Fault Adddress Reporting
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x1bfd920dc):0x1bfd920cc fd 7b c1 a8 c0 03 5f d6 10 29 80 d2 01 10 00 d4 .{......)......
0x1bfd920dc c3 00 00 54 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91 55 d6 ff 97 ...T.{......U...
0x1bfd920ec bf 03 00 91 fd 7b c1 a8 c0 03 5f d6 90 29 80 d2 .....{......)..
0x1bfd920fc 01 10 00 d4 c3 00 00 54 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91 .......T.{......

=================================================================
```

The shared code works perfectly in Android.

What is it going on?

As a final fact. That call is made in the event that is called when a QR code was read.

Thanks

Jaime

Comment: have you tried catching the exception?

Comment: Yes... no exception is thrown. Just the app is closed at that function call.

Comment: Are you using Simulator or Phisical Device?

Comment: @Woj Physical Device. An iPhone 6.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message goes here</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message goes here</string>
```

into your `Info.plist` file

Answer (score 0):

If have had the same problem. I first installed xamarin.essentials and it works. After some experience with xam.plugin.geolocator and xamarin.forms.maps the application crashes on physical device.
I reloaded all nugget packages and deleted the content of the obj folder.
After that everything worked fine.